# What is mSaaS in context of Quickbooks cloud engineering?

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, microservices, multi-tenant

Quote

> Exposure to knowledge in Dockerization and Kubernetes ( **mSaaS**
> technologies) is preferred

What is mSaaS in context of Quickbooks cloud engineering?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSAAS stands for managed software as a service. SaaS applications are standardized software solutions, meaning they can be downloaded and implemented as-is but offer little room for configuration to a specific client's needs. MSaaS applications offer a core software solution, which can be configured to a specific client's needs.

MSaaS provides Greater support, training and account service for subscribers. Project managers and the development team can be looped in for more substantial needs and requests (i.e., custom-building features).

MSaaS can often be used immediately upon download, they’re meant to be configured to each account prior to implementation to offer seamless adoption and maximum value.